# Is changing the meaning of promise methods a good idea?

Tags: javascript, promise, q, nomenclature

I have a long running method in Node.js that keeps listening for command line output until the user *closes* the command or an error halts. Long story short, this method had, among others, three callbacks:

- `on_receive`: Returns any new output from the command line to the callback, either as string or a converted json.
- `on_end`: When the execution is terminated by the user, I send this.
- `on_error`: When the command line prompts an error, I send it to the user. It always means the end of the command line execution, so `on_end` is called afterwards (though it could be called before if needed).

After any time the command is called, I keep the spawned child referenced, so I can kill it later or limit the amount.

Now, I was planning to move to promises (I'm using the library from Kris Kowal, [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), but the three legs of the promise are not exactly how my callbacks are (taken from his wiki):

- `resolve`: Calling resolve with a fulfilled promise causes promise to be fulfilled with the passed promise's fulfillment value.
- `reject`: Calling reject with a reason causes promise to be rejected with that reason.
- `notify`: Calling notify with a value causes promise to be notified of progress with that value. That is, any onProgress handlers registered with promise or promises derived from promise will be called with the progress value.

It would make sense to tie `on_error` to `reject` and maybe `on_end` to `resolve` (although this may also come from an error), but the most important command to track in this case, `on_receive`, is not actually related to a "progress", as the wiki states.

This code I'm doing is a node package for public use, so I don't know if using notify in this way would be actually confusing to other developers.

Comment: How is your "on_receive" not like "progress"?  Sure seems like it is to me.

Comment: Also it looks like you left off the last word of your question so it's not 100% clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, I finished the question (looks like I over-undid). Also, it's not a process that may end any time in the future, just like a `while(true)`, so the concept of progress is not actually there. Therefore my question

Comment: Well if you're going to mold your API around that Promise library, I don't see that you've got any choice. For your model, receiving more data is as close to "progress" as anything else.

Comment: @Pointy Oh well, I noticed something awful: notify and progress are no longer part of `q`. I guess I am not able to continue on this track...

Comment: Does the `on_receive` callback have a return value that is used in the process? I'm not really sure what it does. Can you give an example what you would use it for?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I mentioned it in the question. This callback always returns the output of the command line in the form of a string. It keeps doing so maybe tens of times per minute, until the child commandline process is closed. You could think of this method as a pipe of a streamed `stdout`, though it also processes this output to make it easier to undersand

Comment: If on_receive is called multiple times the solution is simple - use a stream instead of a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is changing the meaning of promise methods a good idea?

Definitely not.

> the three legs of the promise are not exactly how my callbacks are

They don't need to be. Most promises don't even have a notion of progress, that's why it was deprecated in V2. The only thing you need to keep in mind: A promise represent a *result* that will asynchronously become available.

> It would make sense to tie `on_error` to `reject` and maybe `on_end` to `resolve` (although this may also come from an error)

No, `on_end` should not be called from an error. A promise can only either signal the success of a process (*fulfilled*) or failure (*rejected*). A process can't do both.

> the most important command to track in this case, `on_receive`, is not actually related to a "progress"

Yes. A progress is an output signal. The way you describe your `on_receive` callback, it is an *input* to your function that describes how to process some data. It may not be supplied lazily, but is *essential* to the functions operation. In that case, it should simply be (stay) a *parameter*.

Comment: It was deprecated because it is a broken abstraction that doesn't aggregate or compose - not because it wasn't popular in other implementations.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, it's not easily composed in the same manner as promises, that's why most promises didn't use it :-)

Comment: Despite it's closed, I ended up doing this, so thanks!