# How can I get a reference to a promise's deferred object?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

If I have a reference to a promise, how can I get a reference to it's deferred object so that I can use deferred.notify..?

```
var promise = api.get('/some/url').then(function(response){
    var items = [];
    _.each(response.data, function(item){
        // more code to process item
        // how do I get a reference to deferred so I can do a...
        // deferred.notify('processing ' + item.name);
    });
    return items;
});
return promise;
```

Comment: `deferred.notify` sounds like something you'd have in Angular or jQuery? What exactly does the `api.get` function do, or more specifically return ? In `Q` I think `notify` is just an arguments, as in `return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {..`

Comment: api.get returns a promise, currently a [`q`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) promise - but I am trying to simplify it, so will hopefully return a [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a reference to a promise, how can I get a reference to it's deferred object?

You cannot. The promise is the consumer side, it  may only be observed. The deferred is only available to the producer, who can trigger notifications.

What you might be able to do is something along the lines of

```
return api.get('/some/url').then(function(response){
    var items = [];
    var def = Q.defer();
    _.each(response.data, function(item) {
        // do this asynchronously (or there won't be any subscribers yet):
        def.notify('processing ' + item.name);
    });
    def.resolve(items);
    return def.promise;
});
```

The complexity and awkwardness of this is one of the reasons why notifications are deprecated now.

Comment: deprecated in favour of what? can you point me to where the deprecation is explained?

Comment: Deprecated in favour of nothing. It just didn't work out. Most other libs don't implement them, and neither does ES6. Here are some links: https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#refactoring-progress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317744/is-changing-the-meaning-of-promise-methods-a-good-idea#comment43112218_27319959  https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/484

Comment: …and while searching for references, I noticed that we've already got an answer to your problem on SO, so I closed as a dupe :-)